# Symfony Webserver require index.php issue

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

i just updated my symfony version from 3.4.1 to 3.4.2 using composer update command(all OK).

when i tried to start the server i receive the following message:

> Warning: require(index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   (...)vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\Resources\router.php
>   on line 45
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'index.php' 
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in 
>   (...)vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\Resources\router.php
>   on line 45

It makes reference to this peace of code

```
$script = getenv('APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER') ?: 'index.php';

//var_dump(getenv('APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER'));
//die();

    $_SERVER = array_merge($_SERVER, $_ENV);
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$script;

    // Since we are rewriting to app_dev.php, adjust SCRIPT_NAME and PHP_SELF accordingly
    $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$script;
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$script;

    require $script; //<==== HERE!!!
```

When I make a dump in the $script variable my result is false(there is no env variable called APP_FRONT_CONTROLLER) but when I run the server in another 3.4.1 symfony version the result is

> string(11) "app_dev.php"

and all works fine.

Is this an issue of the version or a problem from my env.

If you need more information just ask for it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a flex app or a standard framework app?  Is it a new 3.4.1 app or did you previously upgrade from an earlier version?  And you are using bin/console server:start or run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in 3.4.2 and was already reported:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25515

So only option for now are either downgrading to 3.4.1, use another webserver or fix it and submit a PR.

Comment: Oops.  I just deleted my comment.  I upgraded 4.0.0 to 4.0.2 and it worked fine.  Did not try 3.4 yet.  And I just found out that if I delete a comment then comments that reference it are deleted as well.  Fun stuff.

Comment: Ah yeah, i'm guessing the problem has something to do with the BC layer then for the old structure. Edit: nah i just deleted mine then too since it seemed no longer relevant :D

Comment: I just updated 3.4.1 using the old standard framework style to 3.4.2 and server:start seems to work just fine.

Comment: Interesting. So it's not a general error that's somehow good and bad at the same time. Hopefully the team will figure this out for all those affected.

Comment: [The PR solving this was not part of a release yet. You would need up to depend on 3.4@dev for now.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25515#issuecomment-354069506)